# Load vue app with jsonld data passed as parameter to the url

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

Let's say I have an Vue app http://www.example.com/?url=https://example-data.com/activity-sets/example/sample.jsonld .

I would like the vue app to load the page with the jsonld passed through the path given in the url i.e. https://example-data.com/activity-sets/example/sample.jsonld

The idea is : anyone should be able to modify the url to a different jsonld data located anywhere in the world. How can I achieve this?

I am new to Vue and am not getting a clear idea of what to do.

Comment: He can also make use of the `window.location` javascript object if he does not use any router

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly easy to something like that. Just create a HTML document (index.html) in the root of your webserver and add the following contents:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Vue Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script>
    var $_GET=[];
    window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi,function(a,name,value){$_GET[name]=value;});
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data () {
        return {
          url: $_GET['url']
        }
      },
      template: '<iframe :src="url"></iframe>'
    })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

It will read the `?url=` contents from the url and insert it as an iFrame src.

In **theory** this will do the trick. If you test this with eg. ?url=https://twitter.com/chucknorris you will end up with an "Content Security Policy" violation. Most sites will be secured this way, so you should test this with your purpose.